# How to bind customize function to a create jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create HTML element using jquery like:

```
var $ele = $('<select>',{name: name, class: className});
```

and want to bind custom function to that element like:

```
$ele.testFun = function () { 
    return this.val();
};
```

and I want to use that function back like:

```
$ele.testFun();
```

So, How could I try to get that result pls.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
$.fn.myFunction = function() { 
  return $(this).val();
}

// Now, you can use it like this
$ele.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$ele.testFun = ...` will bind a function to the jQuery wrapper around your element, not to your element. It will work while you use `$ele`; it will not work if you get another jQuery wrapper, or if you invoke it on the element itself, of course.

`$ele.get(0).testFun = ...` will bind the function to the element itself.

If you wish to be able to say `$ele.testFun()` on any jQuery wrapper (and not specifically `$ele`), you need to make a jQuery extension, by defining `$.fn.testFun = ...`.

Comment: But then `this.val()` inside `testFun()` is not defined, it should be `this.value`

Comment: @A.Wolff: I don't know what you mean. It is certainly *different* - but going by what OP said ("want to bind custom function to that element"), I believe `this` being the element and not jQuery wrapper should be more correct. (And yes, `this.val()` will need to be modified into `this.value` or `$(this).val()`)

Comment: Indeed it is what i meant `I believe this being the element and not jQuery wrapper`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to create a custom jQuery plugin.

You need to add the method to the prototype object of jQuery so that jQuery object instances can access them

```
$.fn.testFun = function () { 
    return this.val();
};
```

- [How to Create a Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to what you propose as follows:

```
$.fn.create = function(tagName, attributes)
{
    var attributeString = '';

    for(attribute in attributes)
    {
        attributeString += attribute + '="' + attributes[attribute] + '" ';
    }

    return $(this).append('<' + tagName + ' ' + attributeString + '></' + tagName + '>');
};
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var $ele = $('body').create('select',{name: name, class: className});
```